# What does the highlighted part in the phrase mean?

Tags: meaning

"**Reason is negative** and dialectical because it resolves determinations of understanding into nothing"

What does **reason is negative** mean here? That it is undesireable? Or lacks any characteristics that would make it absolute, or desirable?

I posted this question a while ago, asking for the meaning of the whole phrase and was asked to take it to philosophy stackexchange, which I did. But this time i just want to know what **reason is negative** means, which probably has as much to do with language as philosophy.

And if you could explain what the whole phrase to me, that would just mean a whole lot to me.

Comment: From what text are you getting this? We may be able to tell you based on who it is you’re reading; different philosophers mean different things when they use certain terms, like ‘reason’ or even ‘negative’.

Comment: I actually came across this on reddit, in a meme. But the guy who told me to take it to philosophystackexchange said it was Hegel.

Comment: Ahhh. I can’t tell you the meaning of this, but for future, once you have this question answered, I’d advise you to never read Hegel again; even among English native speakers philosophers he’s held as one of the most difficult, hard-to-understand thinkers.